# Date inserted to database become 0000

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, xampp

so here's my code

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_project (`sampleField`) values(@sample)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sample", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

This is what's happening.
When I run my solution/project on the Unit that have the database through xampp. I can perfectly put the right date on the database.
But when run the solution/project from a different unit and remotely access the database. The date being saved to my database become 0000, not the correct date. How to fix this. Please help.
BTW. I can perfectly remotely insert strings and numbers on the database. the only problem is the date. its becoming null or 0000.

Comment: Do not convert `DateTime` to `String`: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sample", DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't convert the date to string. If you do, the results depend on the culture settings on the computer where you run the code.

Add the parameter as DateTime:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sample", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

It's better to use `Parameters.Add` instead of `AddWithValue` because it lets you specify the data type of the parameter explicitly.